# Geometric interpretation of Holonomy

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a vector bundle with some connection and a closed loop, I get a linear map from the fiber back to itself which tells me what would happen if I parallel transported a vector around that loop. When/how can I look at this linear operator and make some statements about either the manifold/bundle and/or about the curve.

I know that in the limit where the closed curve becomes infinitesimally small, the leading term is proportional to the curvature. I'm also pretty sure that for a 2-d surface the holonomy corresponds to rotating by an angle equal to the integrated gaussian curvature over the region bounded by the curve. Do either of these generalize?

Any resources where I could read up on this would be appreciated as well

Comment: Your second paragraph seems to be about Riemannian connections on a surface. This does generalize to vector bundles, in particular, there is curvature, see [Connection (vector bundle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(vector_bundle)), but it is not as intuitive because the bundle may not be as closely tied to the geometry of the manifold as the tangent bundle of the Riemannian manifold.

Comment: The generalization of the 2-D interpretation in terms of Gaussian curvature (done via Stokes's Theorem) is the [Ambrose-Singer Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy#Ambrose%E2%80%93Singer_theorem).